# datawarehouse star schema fact table? how do you know what goes in there

Tags: sql, data-warehouse

I just want to get my head around dimensional modelling in terms of creating fact table. My understanding of it so far from the kimball book is that a fact table will be a transaction table which will related to dimensional tables to which there is a parent key constraint. Thats part 1 of my question.

Part 2, My confusion is around the fact that fact tables only store foreign keys and numeric values. What if that base transaction table stores dimensional data. What happens to these column/ attribute?

Do they get put to whichever dimensional table they relate to? how would you determine that if there is more than one table that this transaction table has a foreign key constraint.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

With Kimball dimensional models, everything that you'd want to categorize, split, filter or otherwise order your data by goes into dimensions, leaving only the numeric fields that you'd sum, average, etc in the fact table.

Ideally, your dimensions can be reused for all fact tables across your business, giving a consistent view of all the attributes your data has available, and giving the **correct** results when people combine data from different fact tables through shared dimensions.

The second benefit of taking all the text/attributes out of fact tables is their increased performance when the number of rows grows a lot. This used to be a bigger concerns when storage and RAM were much more expensive and of course has been overtaken by the whole Big Data paradigm, but is still valid in any RDBMS.

Regarding part 2 of your question: Operational systems group their data for optimal (write) performance, which generally means storing data together in one table if it is used together in a transaction, and especially not bothering with many lookups and updates to secondary tables. The analysis/DWH side has completely different priorities.

Finally, you will end up with dimensional looking attributes from the original transaction that only make sense for that one table. They can go into junk dimensions or rarely, the fact table itself (degenerate dimension). Both concepts are in the book.